# C++ How to write a friend function binary operator which lives in a namespace in a separate compilation unit

Tags: c++17, operator-overloading, friend-function, binary-operators

I can't seem to figure out how to get the following to compile.

I am trying to write a binary operator which:

- Is defined in a separate compilation unit (file)
- Lives in a nested namespace

Here's some code:

```
// header.h

namespace ns1
{
    namespace ns2
    {

        class myClass
        {

            friend bool operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r);

        protected:

            int a;
        };

    }
}
```

```
// header.cpp

#include "header.h"

using namespace ns1;
using namespace ns1::ns2;

bool operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r)
{
    if(l.a != r.a) return false;
    return true;
}
```

```
// main.cpp

#include "header.h"

using namespace ns1::ns2;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    myClass class1;
    myClass class2;

    if(class1 == class2)
    {
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output from the compiler:

```
In function ‘bool operator==(const ns1::ns2::myClass&, const ns1::ns2::myClass&)’:
error: ‘int ns1::ns2::myClass::a’ is protected within this context
```

I have a suspicion that this is related to the compiler not understanding which namespace `operator==` should be in. I have tried explicitly declaring this, but that didn't help either.

The question is what is going on here? What is the compiler thinking?

**Edit**

Note: I posted this edit in response to an answer which was then deleted. The suggestion was to put the operator inside `ns1::ns2`, however this did not work. See the below output.

New compiler output:

```
error: ‘bool ns1::ns2::operator==(const ns1::ns2::myClass&, const ns1::ns2::myClass&)’ has not been declared within ‘ns1::ns2’ [-Werror]
bool ns1::ns2::operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r)

note: only here as a ‘friend’
friend bool operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is when you declare a friend function inside your class, this function belongs to the innermost enclosing namespace, you have to define

```cpp
bool ns1::ns2::operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r)
```

It should be defined **inside** namespace `ns1::ns2` but not just introduced it with `using` directives,

```cpp
// header.cpp

#include "header.h"

namespace ns1 {
    namespace ns2 {
        bool operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r)
        {
            if(l.a != r.a) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z1aefd8eY)

or

```cpp
// header.h
namespace ns1
{
    namespace ns2
    {

        class myClass
        {
             ...
        };

        bool operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r);
    }
}


// header.cpp
bool ns1::ns2::operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jc7G7a7YT)

---

Another way is to declare your friend function as a global one,

```cpp
// header.h
#pragma once
namespace ns1
{
    namespace ns2
    {
        class myClass;
    }
}

bool operator==(const ns1::ns2::myClass& l, const ns1::ns2::myClass& r);

namespace ns1
{
    namespace ns2
    {

        class myClass
        {

            friend bool ::operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r);

        protected:

            int a;
        };

    }
}

// header.cpp

#include "header.h"

using namespace ns1::ns2;
bool operator==(const myClass& l, const myClass& r)
{
    if(l.a != r.a) return false;
    return true;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rhn89zG5M)

Comment: It might be that I don't understand how to use Godbolt, but the demos you linked to don't appear to do anything. I don't see the usual output from the compiler which I would expect to see (disassembly?) and the program doesn't appear to run after compiling.

Comment: The first part of this answer also appears to be exactly the same as the one which was deleted. (That is why I posted the "Edit" on the question above.) The second part is different, and might work. I will test it and report back.

Comment: I have no idea why godbolt could run the program now. But I can add the assembly code. Forgive me since it's only my habit not showing the assembly.
Solution 1: https://godbolt.org/z/z1aefd8eY
Solution 2: https://godbolt.org/z/T6qPKfhEG
But the way, there might be as expected if nothing is printed since you don't initialize your member `a` which is trivial and they might not be the same.

Comment: Ok, you can check if you agree with these findings, but it seems that your first suggestion does work. (Defining the operator inside two `namespace nsX { }` blocks.) The second suggestion of defining the operator `ns1::ns2::operator==` doesn't seem to work. Error: `bool ns1::ns2::operator== has not been declared in ns1::ns2`. Finally, the third suggestion, of declaring it in global namespace, I did not verify yet.

Comment: Essentially, it seems that the compiler will not accept this: `using namespace ns1::ns2; bool operator==()` and it will also not accept `bool ns1::ns2::operator==`, or `using namespace ns1::ns2; bool ns1::ns2::operator==`. Sorry for the code formatting here, it doesn't work well in comments.

Comment: *The second suggestion of defining the operator ns1::ns2::operator== doesn't seem to work.* Yes, it's my bad...(My compiler only gives a warning though)
The main idea of `using namespace xxx` not working is that `using` directives only introduces names but does not let you define things inside.

Comment: To make my second suggestion work, you must declare the function in the namespace (in the header). I updated it.